# Any difference between returning of(T) and new BehaviorSubject(T)?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm wondering if there is any differences between these two functions:

```
function testObservable(message: string) : Observable<string>{
    return new BehaviorSubject(message);    
}

function testObservable(message: string) : Observable<string>{
    return of(message); 
}
```

I'm returning a `new BehaviorSubject(T)` in a `AsyncValidatorFn` and I'm getting different behavior that if I return the `of(T)`

**UPDATE - VALIDATION CODE**

```
export function createPasswordMatchesWithServerValidator(
  passwordMatchesWithServerService: PasswordMatchesWithServerService
): AsyncValidatorFn {

    const wrongPassword = 'password';

    return (c: FormControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {

        passwordMatchesWithServerService.check(c.value);

        return passwordMatchesWithServerService.checkIfValidOldPassword$.pipe(
          map(response => {
            let error = {};
            error[wrongPassword] = true;
            switch (response.state) {
              case ResponseState.Success:
                console.log('Validation Success: ', response.content);
                break;

              case ResponseState.Failure:
                console.log('Validation Fail: ', response);
                error = {};
                error[wrongPassword] = true;
                break;

              case ResponseState.Loading:
                console.log('Validation Loading...');
                break;
            }
            return error;
          }
        )
    );
  };
}
```

If I return:

```
const error = {};
error[wrongPassword] = true;
return of(error);
```

it just work fine

Comment: Post the code to your AsyncValidatorFn. The only difference in your case is that of completes and the behavior subject doesn't. Without seeing your code it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Observables returned by an AsyncValidatorFn have to complete. `new BehaviorSubject(message)` doesn't complete. If `passwordMatchesWithServerService.checkIfValidOldPassword$` doesn't complete you could add a `take(1)` e.g. `passwordMatchesWithServerService.checkIfValidOldPassword$.pipe(take(1), map(r => ..))`

Comment: Cool, thanks @friddo. So it was a lack of understanding how validator and observables works. So I undestand that BehaviorSubject just complete when I subscribe it, isn't?

Comment: No, a Subject only completes if you call `subject.complete()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Of` completes as soon as all values are emitted and it emits all of them right after subscribtion.

`BehaviorSubject` is observable that can emit values until you close it manually. You can call `.next()` on `BehaviourSubject` instance to emit new value. Every subscriber will get last value emitted by `BehaviorSubject` and all futher ones after the subscribtion.

Multiple subscribtion to `of` will lead to the same result of emitting the same values.

Comment: In these two functions I'm returning an `Observable`, so my question it's about if there is any differences in the result.

Comment: I've already told you. In `BehaviourSubject` you emit values as many and as long as you want

Comment: If we are not providing you the answer you are looking for @Buntupana, consider providing a bit more information. Can you build a stackblitz that demonstrates the issue you need to resolve?

Comment: As mentioned, the difference is BehaviorSubject is still accepting new values to be emitted. So in your code, the only difference is the of() observable completes right after, the BehaviourSubject doesn't.
Async validators do depend upon completion, so that might be the reason you are getting a different behaviour, but we cannot really tell unless you share the validator code.